# How to get new appended elements by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get elements that appended to the DOM by jQuery slice method.

```js
let inx = $('.items').index($("#product1"));
$(".items").slice(inx).html(function(inx) {
  return $(this).text() - 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='items'></div>
  <div class='items'></div>
  <div class='items'></div>
  <div class='items'></div>
  <div class='items' id='product1'>1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was a Typo mistake

Comment: Since you seem to be appending an ID, why not just `$("#id")`?

Comment: So... the code you have is working. What's the question?

Comment: Ids created dynamically.

Comment: yes it works properly in your snippet beacause elements are not appanded here. @ Heretic Monkey

Comment: We're going to need a bit more effort from you... You've asked a question, and included code. Thank you for that. However, the code shows everything working fine. If there is something not working the way you expect, [edit] your question to include text, words, that explain what you want to happen that isn't happening, or what is happening that isn't. Edit the code until it reproduces the situation you have locally.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var inx = $('.items').index($("#product1"));
  console.log("INX: " + inx);
  $(".items").slice(inx).html(function(inx) {
    console.log("THIS: " + $(this).text());
    return $(this).text() - 1;
  });
  $(".items[id^='product']").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id") + ": " + $(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='items'>Item 1</div>
  <div class='items'>Item 2</div>
  <div class='items'>Item 3</div>
  <div class='items'>Item 4</div>
  <div class='items' id='product1'>1</div>
  <div class='items' id='product2'>2</div>
  <div class='items' id='product3'>3</div>
</div>
```

If items are appended and you're unsure of the ID or need to use a variable selector, you might try the attribute selector.